# Finding the maximum of an array recursively

Tags: c, arrays, max

I am learning recursion. As an exercise I am trying to find the maximum of an array  recursively.

```
int recursive (int *arr, int n, int largest) {
  if(n==0)
    return largest;
  else {
    if (*(arr+n)>largest) {
      largest = *(arr+n);
      recursive(arr, n-1, largest);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int length = n-1;
  int largest = v[0];
  int z = recursive(arr, length, largest);

  printf("\n%d", z);
}
```

I followed your suggestions, using pointers instead of arrays, and probably the program looks way better. But still it is not doing it's not showing the maximum correctly. I think the logic is correct.

Comment: read up on how to pass arrays to C functions.

Comment: Check this link, I think it's about how you call your arrays :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm

Comment: int v[n]; doesn't compile for me. Maybe it's my compiler, but it wants "n" to be constant. I think you need to malloc/alloc.

Comment: @ffhighwind `int v[n]` is a Variable Length Array, previously required by the C standard but now optional. MSVC never did implement the VLA.

Comment: You're passing `n+1`th element of an `n` element array instead of passing the whole array.

Comment: The function `recursion()` is declared as `recursion (int *, int, int)` but you are calling it with 3 `int`s instead of one `int *` and 2 `int`s. Also, `index` is a terrible name for what is actually the current maximum; maybe `current_maximum`? Also, you initialize the current maximum with `n`, which is not necessarily even a value in the array. You may want to replace the call with `int z = recursion (v, n - 2, v [n - 1])`.

Answer (score 0):

In C *usually* you can't declare an array whose size is unknown at compile-time, hence `int v[n]` is dangerous code.
Depending on your compiler and the compiler's settings this could be a compile error or it could be a bug.

For such problems you need to learn about pointers and [dynamic memory allocation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-dynamic-memory-allocation/).

Side-note: After C99 there are stuff like [*Variable Length Arrays*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm) but the rules are a little advanced.

Also to [pass an array to a function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm) you give the array a pointer as an argument:

```
int z = recursion(v, n, v[0]);
```

instead of:

```
int z = recursion(v[n], n, v[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing pay attention to compiler warnings, your recursive function doesn't return value when you enter the else part.

Now the second thing is please don't use things like *(arr+n) which is hard to read instead use arr[n], also while just a preference when using arrays as function arguments use int arr[] to call the function instead of int *arr (in the first version it's clear you should pass an array).

Third thing is to name your things instead of `int recursive` describe what the function is doing for example `int maxElemRecursive`

So your recursive function should be something like

```
int maxElemRecursive(int arr[],int n,int largest)
{
    if(n==0) return largest;
    if(arr[n] > largest) // No need for else because return largest; would've returned value;
    {
        largest = arr[n]; 
    }
    return maxElemRecursive(arr,n-1,largest); // You have to return the value of the function.
                                             // You still pass the array with just arr.
}
```